# Use state token inside axios instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, axios

I have a state with a token that i get from my api :

```
const initialState = {
  isAuth: false,
  token: "",
};
```

And I want to reuse the token in an Axios instance :

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${baseUrl}`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
});

export default api;
```

The problem is that I can not read the token via useSelector as :

```
const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);
```

I get the error message :

> invalid hook call. hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component

Any suggestion ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use hooks outside of function components or other hooks. However, you can create the axios instance without the token, and then update the instance (`api`) when you have it (see axios's [Config Defaults](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults)).

Note: you'll need to prevent your app from using the axios instance before the token is set.

Define the `api` without the `authorization` header:

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${baseUrl}`,
});
```

In one of your top components get the token, and apply it to the axios instance defaults:

```
const App = () => {
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(token) {
      api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
  }, [token]);
}
```

Comment: your solution is good and it works. Note that instead of axios.defaults, i used api.defaults

Comment: Yea. It was supposed to be `api` (axios instance) in the answer as well. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It is because a **hook can only be used inside a React Component**.
To be able to retrieve this state, the ideal is to store it in the **localStorage**.
The **localStorage** can be **accessed at any level** (React components or not)

You need to **create a new value** in the localStorage in this way:

```
localStorage.setItem("myToken",value)
```

Then you can use it inside the axios instance like this :

```
localStorage.getItem("myToken")
```

Hope it helps !

> imo you should also use the [Interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)  for axios to handle the accesstoken

> **Resource**
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure where your useSelector is called exactly (and also where the other code fragments are placed inside your code) but your specific error message makes it clear, that your are calling the useSelector-hook not directly inside a functional component.

I would suggest you to read the following article: [Hooks Rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

There it says:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to wrap your Axios code in a custom hook function. This will allow you to use other hook functions – including accessing your Redux state via `useSelector`.

For example:

```
const useApi = () => {
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.auth.token);

  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseUrl,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });

  return api;
}

export default useApi;
```